# What happens at Spellhold if you leave Yoshimo behind?

Tags: baldurs-gate-2

Yoshimo is magically compelled to betray you to Irenicus at Spellhold but- if you either don't include him in your party or dismiss him before going to Spellhold, how does your encounter with Irenicus when he does away with his disguise as a doctor then admits to planting Yoshimo with you end?

Answer (score 8):

The confrontation with Irenicus at Spellhold ends when...

> Irenicus flees, leaving you to face another group of "murderers".

If Yoshimo was in your party and compelled to betray you, then he enters the scene after this and...

> ...attacks you. When you defeat him, you can take his heart to undo the Geas on Yoshimo, starting a quest to reconcile him with his god Ilmater and give him peace in death.

If Yoshimo was not in your party when you went to Spellhold...

> ...he will not be there to challenge you, leaving you free to escape.

In this case, then if you encounter him later on...

> ...he will immediately die because of his Geas. In this case, there's no option of reconciling Yoshimo with Ilmater since he drops no heart.

Sources: [1](http://www.tgeweb.com/ironworks/baldursgate2/walkthrough-chapter04.shtml), [2](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Yoshimo)